# Where to get props and set props in a functional component in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-props, prop

```
props data coming from the parent component

const [state, setState] = useState({

reportTypesVal: { label: "", value: "" } || props?.reportTypesVal});
```

> Why I'm unable to set data like this to reportTypesVal?
> If I try to set data in useEffect It doesn't set the value to reportTypesVal.
> How can I do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. `||` doesn't make sense here since it can never be falsy. Please clarify your question. See [mre].

Comment: Have you considered keeping this child as a controlled component (thereby, a single source of truth for `reportTypesVal`) and using a callback function (from the parent) being passed via props? Your events in the child need to simply trigger the parent's update-handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but from the title:

> Where to get props and set props in a functional component in React Js?

I assume you're asking how to pass props, here is an example on the new beta documentation: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Comment: Actually, I wanna ask How to set props data in a state of the functional component?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement it in the child name function.

EX:

```
import ...
import ...

function showSomething( {MyProps1, MyProps2} )  // <---- here
{
   useEffect(() => {
        
        console.log(MyProps1);      

   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass props into a component:

```
<Component property={'randomText'} />
```

This is how you retrieve it in the component:

```
function Component (props) = {
  return (
    <p>{props.property}</p>
  )
}
```

You can change the property inside of the component by using states and passing the set function as a property:

```
const [randomText, setRandomText] = React.useState('randomText')
return(
    <Component property={randomText} propertySet={setRandomText} />
)
```

Inside the component you can do:

```
function Component (props) = {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => {props.setRandomText('randomText2')}}>{props.randomText}</button>
      )
    }
```

Then when you click the button it will change to 'randomText2'

Comment: I know that you answered me. But I have a question How to set the data of props in a state of the functional component?

Comment: The third block of code answers your question